# Follow your friends on StackOverflow with FriendOverflow

Tags: app, firefox, bookmarklet, google-chrome

### Screenshot

[image]

### Video of app in action

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0zflMRXt2c&hd=1

### About

I created this app because I wanted to see what my friends and co-workers were doing on StackOverflow. I was previously going to their profiles to see what they were asking, answering, and commenting on because most of the time I found what they were doing was interesting or relevant to what I was doing.

This app is for anyone who visits StackOverflow using their desktop browser and has 'friends' they would like to follow on StackOverflow.

#### Cost

Free

#### Download

Google Chrome extension http://goo.gl/ooE34

Mozilla Firefox extension http://goo.gl/3Pnqa

Bookmarklet http://goo.gl/FkuQW

#### Platform

Desktop browsers via Google Chrome extension, Mozilla Firefox extension, and bookmarklet

### Contact

[@MikeGrace](http://twitter.com/MikeGrace)

### Code

App was built on the [Kynetx](http://www.kynetx.com/) [platform](http://www.kynetx.com/platform/) using KRL (Kynetx Rule Language)

Comment: Cool! I'm psyched to try this out. :)

Comment: +1 for the first KRL app around - quite interesting :) Are you going to publish the source and/or is Kynetx considering to provide an 'official' Stack Exchange KRL library, i.e. in the spirit of the integrations for [Amazon, GData, OData et al.](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/MediaWiki:KRLlibraries)?

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. I do plan on publishing the source once I clean it up a bit more. As for the integration, because KRL now has the beginnings of modules (http://goo.gl/y3SDS), I am currently converting the app over to use a StackExchange module a buddy of mine has built.  : ) Thanks for adding the krl tag.

Comment: @Steffen Opel - does this work.  how do you add people in your list.  I only see options when brings up a screen that says domains which only had stackoverflow.com

Comment: @ooo - the extensions don't work for me currently either, neither in Firefox nor in Chrome: both are showing an endless loop of self closing popups with the message _FriendOverflow - Thanks for being logged in_; disabling and enabling the extension in Chrome disabled it entirely now, so we'll need @Mike to jump in here with information/analysis.

Comment: @ooo & @Steffen, I'm sorry to hear that the app isn't working for you. I tested it again this morning and created a screencast of how it works. Do you have cookies enabled and are you logged in to StackOverflow?

Comment: @Mike - thanks for adding the screencast, quite helpful in understanding the intention! For my part the problem has indeed been a mixture of 3rd party cookie and script blocking (you seem to require dropbox.com?!), enabling both resolved the issue; blocking 3rd party cookies triggers the mentioned endless loop, blocking dropbox removed the UI buttons (and in turn any clue regarding the intended functionality, see comment by @ooo), so obviously both would benefit from a more graceful error handling depending on how much this is intended to be a Kynetx showcase app as well ;)

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. The Dropbox stuff is my resource files since it makes quick development easy as I am still developing it and will move the resource files to a better location soon. Thanks for the feedback and I will look into seeing how to more gracefully handle these issues.

Comment: you should consider pulling in the new network-wide profiles as well: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: I love that idea! The app needs a major refresh also. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MikeGrace, just wondering what's going on with this addon? I tried it with FF 10.0.1 and it isn't supported. Is the source for this plugin anywhere that others could check it out?

Comment: @slm, I haven't tested it yet but you may be able to get it to work from http://apps.kynetx.com/installable_apps/1009-FriendOverflow I built the app on top of the Kynetx platform. I still like the idea of what I did but it needs to be overhauled and updated severely.

Comment: @MikeGrace, OK I'm getting a little bit further. I was able to install the Kynetx Firefox plugin, and then install the FriendOverflow plugin on top of it. I'm getting the FriendOverflow on the main page, when I click it I get the box that says I have no friends 8-( with a link to you, I click that but the user details page is missing the FriendOverflow button. Any hints on how to debug would be appreciated. I like the idea of this plugin and would be willing to spend time trying to get it working with a little help/guidance.

Comment: @slm, good to hear that you made it through the install process. The "follow" button probably isn't showing up on user's profiles because the markup of the page has probably changed. The app will need to be updated to work with the new markup or changed to not rely on page markup.

Comment: I love the idea of this app.  I installed it on Chrome on Mac OS X, but I'm not seeing the "Add as friend" button on StackOverflow user pages.  I see the "FriendOverflow" on question pages, but it only takes me to the info popup.

Comment: This app is really old and hasn't been updated in a long time. Looks like it's time for a refresh and to go back to the drawing board for features and design. This could be a lot better :)

Comment: As a newbie here, how to install this app on the chrome extension. I downloaded it, but couldn't upload it to chrome extension. Please guide me how can I put this app on my stackoverflow page. Thank very much!

Comment: @MikeGrace You might wanna try out [StackEye](http://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites). StackEye allows you to follow your favorite users and you get their notifications in extension popup. Just checkout the screenshots [here](http://blunderboy.github.io/stackeye/)