# StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, notifier

[StackEye](http://blunderboy.github.io/stackeye/) is a Chrome extension which can be used to **follow other users** for their answers and questions. Using StackEye you can also **add a question to your watchlist** there by getting notifications for each answer/comment on it. StackEye v1.0 is available in [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm) and source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/stackxyz/stackeye). Please feel free to fork and give any feedback.

Some features:

- No login/authentication required.
- Works on any question (not just those asked by you).
- Watch or unwatch questions with a single click.
- **Follow your favorite users (New)**
- View list of all notifications and questions.
- Works on all Stack Exchange sites.

These snapshots will help you understand what StackEye is:

- Click the eye icon to watch and unwatch a question.

  > Not watching (click to watch): [image]

  > Watching (click to unwatch): [image]
- Go to profile page of any user to follow him

  > [image]
- How it looks when you are following a user

  > [image]
- Watched questions will display notifications in the extension's popup window.

  > [image]
- Followed Users will display notifications in extension's popup window.

  > [image]
- Notifications can be deleted (acknowledged) in bulk from this screen.

  > [image]
- A list of watched questions is also available; questions can be unwatched in bulk from this screen.

  > [image]
- A list of follow users is also available. Users can be unfollowed in bulk from here.

  > [image]

Comment: Hi, could you update the extension to support the new [so] localized sites? E.g.: [pt.so]. Thanks!

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the request. I have opened a https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/issues/31 to add localization feature. I am little busy these days but I will definitely catch this up and work on it.

Comment: @brasofilo I have updated the extension to support the localized sites as well. Please let me know if that works for you. I have also published the extension so update will be available in chrome store soon. Check out the commits here https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/commits/master

Comment: Yes! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: This is a fabulous tool!  Alas, it doesnt not work with the new SO user profile page, so there is no way to add users anymore.

Comment: @Plutonix  I will push an update soon to fix the issue. May be you can open an issue on github and I will work on it on priority. Thanks for submitting

Comment: So the data stored in this extension is device dependent ? If I am using two Google chrome, I can't have the data in my all devices ??

Comment: @OSryx Currently it is not supported. But I do have plans to add it in future. Chceckout this issue: https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/issues/33. These days I am mostly busy with my other Chrome Extension, Requestly but I do have certain plans to add more things in StackEye and make UI more beautiful

Comment: I love StackEye ... anyway keep up with good work

Comment: This looks great, any chance you could add the ability to watch tags as well as specific questions?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I had plans for adding this feature to follow tags.[Github Issue](https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/issues/14) but I haven't had time to implement that..I will surely consider adding this in future..

Answer (score 10):

[StackEye v2.0](https://github.com/stackxyz/stackeye) brings another great feature viz **Follow users on all StackExchange sites**. Just go to the profile page of the user and click Follow and there you go.

All the [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) fans, this feature is for you. Follow him and get informed of all the posts made by him. Keep learning from his great answers and questions. There are too many experts out here on StackExchange like Jon Skeet including (RobW, Barmar, VonC, TJ Crowder, Felix Kling and a lot others). I can't name all. Just follow your favorite ones and keep learning.

StackEye is also avaible in [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm). **I have updated the new screenshots (as per 2.0) in my original question.**

Feel free to report any bugs, suggest new features. I will be more than happy to discuss anything about it. Here is the [github reporsitory of StackEye](https://github.com/stackxyz/stackeye)

Comment: I am using your addon, its wonderful and timesaving. But, the restriction of 20 questions is difficult to manage. Why is there such restriction on first place?

Comment: @talegari Its nice and valid question. I just do not want users to watch a lot of questions and then they receive too many notifications.  I believe 20 is a good limit because most of the time we want to follow latest questions only. However, I can increase that to 30 or 40 if more people towards it. I am glad you like it.

Comment: I do find a necessity of following a lot more questions. So, plus 1 on increasing the bound.

Comment: One more suggestion: Given that some limit is present on the number of questions that one can follow, it would be good to make the questions/ list as 'FIFO' and a warning saying question 1 is going to be removed when user tries to add the 21st question. This will help avid users like me from spending time on cleaning up the list of questions I am tracking.

Comment: @talegari That is a nice suggestion indeed. I hope I get some time to implement this. Can I ask you to rate it and give your honest feedback on chrome store ?

Comment: About feedback, yes, I will do it immediately. One more thing to add: Its better to allow some questions to be 'sticky' (a boolean), so that a sticky question stays and would not exit the list.

Comment: @talegari Do you mean like bookmarking a question and showing in the list ? If I understand correctly, this feature is already present on stackoverflow and I have already opened a task for it https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/issues/2. Though it is not yet done. I will take out sometime and do it. Thanks again!!

Comment: Great extension overall, but why the limit?! Why would you care how many questions one wishes to watch?

I think you should allow an unlimited amount of watched questions. Otherwise, it is useless for me. (I can answer more than 20 questions in a single day.)

Comment: @YisroelTech There are a couple of reasons for the limit - 1. I don't want users to follow any number of questions and get frustrated later about too many notifications. I want them to follow only the questions they are seriously concerned about getting notifications. 2. There are limits with local storage where I store all this data.

Comment: @sachinjain024 I think you should at least give an option to change it for the Stack Exchange nerds who do seriously follow a lot more than 20 questions. Meanwhile I downloaded it from GitHub and edited the file to allow more, and loaded it as a developer in Chrome...

Comment: @sachinjain024 Is a way to view the updates grouped by the SE site (rather than just by user/question)?

Comment: @user7 That is a good suggestion actually! I am not actively working on this project anymore. I can willing to help if someone wants to take over the project.

Comment: The "Follow" option no longer seems to work.  Will you be fixing this soon?  - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ChileAddictPMP for notifying me. I am not very much active on this project these days but I will fix this one on weekend.

Comment: Update - I removed the extension from Chrome and added it again.  After doing that I found that if you go into the user's profile and then to the Activity Tab, there is an option to Follow/Unfollow again.  However, I of course, lost all my data to I had to go back and re-follow everyone, which was a pain.  Is there any way, Stack Eye could keep our profile information so that we don't lose it if we need to remove it then re-install it?