# Version used by StackExchange API if version is not specified in api calls

Tags: discussion, api, documentation

I have used some StackExchange API calls in [my chrome extension - StackEye](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites). With the release of API 2.0, I want to update the api calls so I wanted to know

- New things available in 2.0+ which were not available earlier (**Effectively changelogs**)
- Difference between the following two api calls

> https://api.stackexchange.com/posts/18829971;18830520;18830230/comments?site=stackoverflow

AND

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/18829971;18830520;18830230/comments?site=stackoverflow

Please note that in 2nd call, I have specified api version **(2.2)** to be used. Which api version is used behind the scenes if I do not specify api version in my api call ?

Comment: Fun. Some paths (like `search/excerpts`) give different results between explicit version (2.2) and no version!  Otherwise, the version *seems* to default to 2.2 if not specified. ... [Here's a link to the change log](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log)

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks man!! How do I ensure that version is 2.2 (default) if not specified.

Comment: You can't. You have to trust the API developer.  Although, if you call a route that's only available in 2.2, you are *probably* getting 2.2 (or some later beta).  To be sure and to avoid "time-bomb code", **always specify the version in your API calls**.