# StackExchange API JS SDk

Tags: discussion, library, javascript

I am planning to write a javascript library as a wrapper over StackExchange API. Currently, every webapp using StackExchange api needs to compile the url and make a GET request (mostly by ajax) which is somewhat repetitive and can be avoided.

I have started ground level work. I have created repository and already have some helper code which I used in my StackExchange api based app - [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/20686). Code is present on [github](https://github.com/stackeye-pro/stackeye/blob/master/src/shared/api_methods.js).

Idea is if you need to get all the comments for a list of posts. You can call a method like a method like this:

```
SE.getCommentsOnPost(postList, { site: 'stackoverflow' }, function(commentList) {
  // Consume commentList
});
```

I just want to know the following

- Is there any existing js sdk for stackexchange apis ?
- Is it a fair idea to develop such library ?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, you can write your own apis for stack exchange. Also, there is a auth sdk provided by the api team, and it's official

Comment: @UniquekekitteanateUnidoggy Yeah I have plans to include that sdk in our api as well. Essentially, my idea is to encapsulate that sdk with in proposed library and provide rich set of methods